# How to change lockscreen display time on Samsung Galaxy S4 Plus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

When I press the power button the screen is immediately turned off and locked. When I press the power button again the screen is turned on and the lockscreen is displayed. However, it is only displayed for about 5 seconds before the screen goes off again. I have to start interacting with it straight away to prevent the screen from turning off. I don't always want to unlock the screen, sometimes I just like to press the power button to have the screen turn on so I can work my way in the dark, as a flash light replacement. But that doesn't work if I have to keep pressing the power button on and off all the time.

Is it possible to change this time? I would like to have it set to at least 30 seconds, or have it stay on all the time until I press the power button again. Is this possible?

I'm not sure it's possible to have the screen stay on until you press the power button, but my old HTC had a longer display time when the lockscreen is shown.

I'm on Galaxy S4 Plus (GT-I9506) with Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean). It's stock ROM and everything, brand new.

I tried to google this and it appears that the only time setting you can change for the lockscreen is the time it takes for the lockscreen to actually activate. Below is a screenshot of the "Lock screen" page on an Galaxy S3 with Jelly Bean.

[image]

(image source: [Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii/234569-lock-screen-problems-since-jb-update.html))

There was this "Secured lock time" option. It said "the screen will be locked after 30 minutes of inactivity." This is on the Galaxy S3. Mine is a little bit different. Below is a screenshot of the lock screen page on mine.

[image]

This however does not change the display time of the actual screenlock... screen (sorry). It only defines when the screenlock will become active.

Comment: This is not a big issue for me. I'm just curious to know if it's possible to change this, if they have thought about it when they designed the thing. Displaying the lockscreen for only 5 seconds is a bit too short a time window, don't you think? Unless of course you're a gunslinger who's very fast on the trigger. If there's no way of changing this, if it's permanent then they should have used a longer time window. (Well of course, it's not carved in stone, but I mean without having to root it, flash it, format it and what not, just to change this.)

Comment: A time window of maybe 20 seconds would have been much more generous. In only 5 seconds I can't even change hand, and these big phones need to be handled with two hands. At the time I'm ready to enter my pattern or PIN code the screen is off.

Comment: You guys, it's so dumb. I've spent so long trying to figure it out for my step dad. Turns out, the lock screen will stay on for as long as it's pointed at your face. As soon as it doesn't recognize that a face is in front of it, it turns off. Spent so long being so confused.

Comment: Hi, @Erin, and welcome to Android.SE!  Thank you for your comment.  We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay.  What make and model of phone is your stepdad using?  Is it a Samsung Galaxy S4 Plus (GT-I9506), the same as the original asker is using, or is it a different phone?